# Text not vertically aligning in Gmail android app

Tags: android, html, css, gmail, html-email

I have an avatar in my email template showing only the first letter of text inside a round background. Since I can't use JavaScript in email templates, I am using only CSS to achieve this. Here is the html I am using:

```html
<div style='width: 36px; height: 36px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #625fff; border-radius: 36px; line-height: 36px;'>
      <p style='width: 1ch; height: 36px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 36px; margin: 0px auto; word-break: break-all; overflow: hidden; letter-spacing: 18px; color: white; font-family: monospace, monospace; vertical-align: middle;'>John Doe</p>
</div>
```

I am getting the expected result with this code everywhere I tested except the Gmail android app. Here are screenshots from the app:

[image]

As you can see, the text isn't vertically aligned. Since it is in the app and not in the browser, I can't inspect elements to debug the issue.

What could be the reason of text not aligning properly in the app? And what is the solution?

**UPDATE 1**

Tried to fix this by getting rid of `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` and used `display: table` and `display: table-cell` instead. Didn't fix the problem. it still looks the same in the Gmail app. Here is the updated code:

```html
<div style='width: 36px; height: 36px; display: table; background-color: #625fff; border-radius: 36px;'>
      <div style='width: 1ch; height: 36px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 36px; margin: 0px auto; word-break: break-all; overflow: hidden; letter-spacing: 18px; color: white; font-family: monospace, monospace;'>Sadman Rizwan</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have found out that, the line height of the text is greater than the height of the parent div and that is why the text isn't vertically aligned inside the parent div. But I don't know how is this possible since I have set 36px for both. I also don't know if the parent div is getting smaller or the line height getting higher in the Gmail app. Is there any way to find that out?

**UPDATE 3**

Finally, I was able to fix the issue by using `display: table-cell` for vertical alignment rather than relying on `line-height`. Here is the final code:

```html
<div style="width: 36px; height: 36px; border-radius: 36px; background-color: #625fff; text-align: center; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div style="width: 1ch; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; font-family: monospace, monospace; text-transform: uppercase; background-color: #625fff; color: white; font-size: 18px; line-height: normal; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">John Doe</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mail clients have a lot of restrictions, from what I've recently learned, its best to implement the `<table>`s for email for correct layouting.

Comment: @darshan, yes I know, that's why I tried to implement it with common stylings that should be supported. And I am facing the issue in Gmail android app only.

Comment: May be this is out of context, but have you checked in outlook email clients.. how is border radius supported there?

Comment: @SahilDhir, yes, I have checked in the Outlook Android app. I don't see any problem with border-radius there.

Answer (score 0):

The elements associated with `flex` like `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` do not work in Gmail, you need to remove them and use other ways to align your elements so it will work on Gmail

Comment: I know that flex isn't supported. Didn't know that `inline-block` is also not supported. I will try with `table` and give an update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a table, apply styles inline on a td, and only include the first character from the name. Consider the original and suggested code below.

```html
<!-- Original -->
<div style="width: 36px; height: 36px; border-radius: 36px; background-color: #625fff; text-align: center; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
  <div style="width: 1ch; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; font-family: monospace, monospace; text-transform: uppercase; background-color: #625fff; color: white; font-size: 18px; line-height: normal; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">John Doe</div>
</div>

<hr>

<!-- Suggested -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-spacing:0 !important; border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="center" width="36" height="36" bgcolor="#625fff" style="border-radius:36px; font-family:Lucida, monospace; font-size:18px; line-height:18px; color:#ffffff;">
      J
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Assuming you're trying to reach the widest audience possible, you can see how the `table` instance holds up compared to the `<div>` instance when tested among various email clients and devices.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: The question is specifically about a mail client that is not Outlook.

Comment: In fact, OP says in comments "yes, I have checked in the Outlook Android app. I don't see any problem with border-radius there"

Comment: My answer attempts to provide the best solution based on reaching the widest audience, which is what I assume Sadman is after based on the fact that his testing includes Gmail and Outlook (and most likely others). I've updated my answer to make that clearer.